# How does changing method of requesting reviews for mobile apps affect the ratings?

Tags: mobile, users, research, mobile-application

I am looking for statistics on how changing how you ask users to rate your mobile app can drastically change user ratings.

Other questions have just asked for ways, pros or cons, but I am specifically looking for statistics.

Comment: I couldn't find reliable stats but I can tell you it matters how you ask for ratings.  (1) don't ask before i've used your app (2) if i just accomplished something awesome and not in the middle of accomplishing my next awesome thing then go ahead and ask "Do you like us? Consider giving us a 5 star rating."

Comment: Voting to close because this question does not have the best interests of the **user** at heart. Determining the best way to raise your app's ratings is a **dark pattern**; it may increase your rating, but will do so at the cost of making the rating system inaccurate and thus **decreasing trust** in the validity of your ranking.

Comment: @3nafish It is not always a dark pattern. I must insist that asking users to rate an applications is very important, this could be easily achieved without deceiving the users. In my last application, I tried requesting users via emails, that worked pretty well for me, users were happy, most of them were 5 star ratings. I didn't got any 1 star rating just because my app missed a feature. So, I am looking for more better options to make it work, e.g. like trying to "Bake it into UI" as Dan Counsell says, but needs research to support my thesis.

Comment: So you mean when you say "changing review request drastically changed the user ratings" you actually mean "changing review request drastically changed the **number of** user ratings"?  If that's the case, why accept an answer that explains how to increase the ratings themselves?

Comment: @3nafish It is a suggestion, and only answer that I've received (sadly!). If not drastically, but I can definitely say considerably. When I develop an app saying "hey! this app will do XYZ" and people just give it one star citing "It doesn't do WXY" it is damaging. 

I am sure you'll understand how much it hurts to someone who lives solely by developing apps, and providing a 100 feature app is no solution either. So, I'm looking around for solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StumbleUpon team created a custom messaging campaign that asked users if they wanted to rate the app 5 stars. The message was targeted only to returning users, increasing the likelihood this group had a positive first experience with StumbleUpon’s app and would be more likely to accept the prompt. Satisfied users who were willing to rate the app could opt-in to the message and continue on to the rating screen. Users that declined the message for whatever reason would not be taken to the ratings screen.

[image]

This increased the number of 5 star ratings.

[Find the original story here.](https://www.leanplum.com/c/blog/how-stumbleupon-optimized-5-star-app-ratings-using-custom-in-app-messages/)

Comment: Thanks Pj, can you cite some other examples with some statistics. It'll be really helpful. :-)

Comment: Sure @steve, I will add more examples in the next edit.

Answer (score 2):

[Study: Users Both Mostly Positive And Inconsistent In Reviewing iOS App Store Titles](http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/05/apple-app-store-reviews-reviewers-bias-positive/)

> Empatika used sentiment analysis to analyze around 500,000 reviews and see what reviewers were saying about some popular App Store titles, including Facebook, Twitter, YouTube, Instagram and more. What they found was that of the reviewers covered in the survey, a massive 52 percent posted only positive reviews, while 43 percent posted both good and bad reviews, and only a tiny 5 percent had registered only negative feedback through the App Store itself.
>
> There’s a tendency on the part of app users to only express themselves via Apple’s official marketplace channels when they’re pleased with something, Annakov says, which means that if app developers are just looking at App Store reviews, they aren’t getting the full picture of why their app maybe isn’t doing as well as it could be.

This extract from the article supports asking users to review your app after a positive experience, i.e offering the chance to submit feedback when something has been achieved.

> What’s the best strategy for App Store developers to take advantage of reviewer positivity bias, and also get some meaningful negative feedback as well? Annakov suggests soliciting an App Store review from your users, but only after they’ve spent a certain amount of time in-app – finding a threshold where engagement levels appear to indicate a positive experience will result in higher ratings. Also, build in a separate feedback tool, where you can solicit honest opinions via direct contact with your users, instead of through the App Store mechanism, which limits what kind of access you can have.

---

Circa news have written an article on how they received reviews on their app which contains some stats.

[Circa news - The right way to ask users to review your app](https://medium.com/circa/the-right-way-to-ask-users-to-review-your-app-9a32fd604fca)

> As it stands today, out of 8,699 ratings over the life of the app, Circa News has had 315 one star ratings on the App Store. The vast majority of those were within the first few hours of launch two years ago, when our service was unreachable due to our servers struggling to keep up with the massive traffic. We’ve now spent two years building up our ratings in the hopes that those first few ugly hours don’t haunt us permanently. Over the life of the app now, we have 93% four and five star ratings.

This increase in high quality reviews came from 3 factors:

> There are three simple rules:
>
> 1. Don’t interrupt someone’s experience.
> 2. Don’t ask for an app rating after your app has crashed. That’s just stupid.
> 3. Do delay asking for a rating until there’s a likely moment of constructive feedback (as you’ll read later), or a positive rating.

[image]